# How can i convert an image to notification icon to use in android app?

Tags: android, notifications, icons

I have tried built in tools in android studio using **res -> new -> Image Asset** and then selecting notification icon.But after selecting the images it shows some grey and black boxes and not image icon and doesn't show in notifications as well.
I have researched and found that image background should be transparent for it to work but that didn't work also. Also i have tried images of 24x24 size as recommended but couldn't get the icon working in my android app.
Thanks in advance for any useful suggestions.

Comment: Install `Android Drawable Importer` plugin to import images/icons

Comment: will this help me to create icons or just import already created icons in android project?

Comment: Import images to differents resolution and search icons

Comment: Use silhouette icons for notification. Currently above 5.0 silhouette icons will support in notification bar.

Answer (score 0):

For v21 and above--> In notification icon, only white and transparent colors are allowed. Use white color what u want to show, rest part make it transparent.

For v20 and below --> You can use any image with proper dimensions.

Refer [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_status_bar.html) for details.